# How can I install php5-pgsql on a Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, php

I tried these commands to install php5-pgsql but I got an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-pgsql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-pgsql' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP5 packages are not available in Stretch (see [the package lists for `php5-pgsql`](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-pgsql), and note that there are packages for Wheezy, Jessie and Sid, but **not** Stretch). You can either:

- Use PHP7 and install [`php7.0-pgsql`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php7.0-pgsql) and any other relevant packages for PHP7.
- Use an alternative package source like [deb.sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/), which offers PHP 5 packages for Debian 9 (and this includes ARM builds that are compatible with the Pi).